# Get keys and values ​from object from JSON url in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have this const url that I have to get 4 keys and values of "current": "dt":1643884851, "temp":8.11 and in "weather" I have to get "description":"few clouds" and "icon":"02d".
After that, I have to get the same keys and values of all objects in daily.
How can I do this?

```
const url = '{"lat":39.7436,"lon":-8.8071,"timezone":"Europe/Lisbon","timezone_offset":0,"current":{"dt":1643884851,"sunrise":1643874091,"sunset":1643910991,"temp":8.11,"feels_like":6.94,"pressure":1025,"humidity":87,"dew_point":6.08,"uvi":1.63,"clouds":20,"visibility":7000,"wind_speed":2.06,"wind_deg":160,"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}]},"daily":[{"dt":1643889600,"sunrise":1643874091,"sunset":1643910991,"moonrise":1643880300,"moonset":1643920800,"moon_phase":0.08,"temp":{"day":9.56,"min":8.11,"max":14.8,"night":10.29,"eve":11.42,"morn":8.61},"feels_like":{"day":9.15,"night":9.8,"eve":10.78,"morn":8.61},"pressure":1025,"humidity":81,"dew_point":6.47,"wind_speed":2.51,"wind_deg":279,"wind_gust":2.99,"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"clouds":36,"pop":0,"uvi":2.12},{"dt":1643976000,"sunrise":1643960432,"sunset":1643997463,"moonrise":1643968320,"moonset":1644011220,"moon_phase":0.12,"temp":{"day":14.02,"min":9.3,"max":14.86,"night":9.66,"eve":11.67,"morn":9.3},"feels_like":{"day":13.17,"night":8.63,"eve":10.96,"morn":9.3},"pressure":1026,"humidity":65,"dew_point":7.18,"wind_speed":3.71,"wind_deg":335,"wind_gust":5.97,"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":100,"pop":0,"uvi":1.99},{"dt":1644062400,"sunrise":1644046772,"sunset":1644083936,"moonrise":1644056160,"moonset":1644101520,"moon_phase":0.15,"temp":{"day":14.98,"min":8.24,"max":16.46,"night":9.23,"eve":10.87,"morn":8.6},"feels_like":{"day":14.1,"night":8.89,"eve":10.23,"morn":8.6},"pressure":1026,"humidity":60,"dew_point":6.78,"wind_speed":2.88,"wind_deg":336,"wind_gust":4.08,"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":83,"pop":0,"uvi":2.57},{"dt":1644148800,"sunrise":1644133110,"sunset":1644170408,"moonrise":1644143940,"moonset":1644191700,"moon_phase":0.18,"temp":{"day":17.47,"min":8.59,"max":19.18,"night":11.06,"eve":13.31,"morn":8.59},"feels_like":{"day":16.4,"night":9.81,"eve":12.34,"morn":7.67},"pressure":1028,"humidity":43,"dew_point":4.4,"wind_speed":2.22,"wind_deg":18,"wind_gust":3.79,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":1,"pop":0,"uvi":2.62},{"dt":1644235200,"sunrise":1644219446,"sunset":1644256880,"moonrise":1644231840,"moonset":0,"moon_phase":0.22,"temp":{"day":18.22,"min":8.77,"max":19.22,"night":10.85,"eve":12.93,"morn":8.77},"feels_like":{"day":16.93,"night":9.3,"eve":11.56,"morn":7.52},"pressure":1028,"humidity":32,"dew_point":0.71,"wind_speed":3.49,"wind_deg":107,"wind_gust":5.75,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":3,"pop":0,"uvi":2.59},{"dt":1644321600,"sunrise":1644305782,"sunset":1644343352,"moonrise":1644319800,"moonset":1644281820,"moon_phase":0.25,"temp":{"day":17.33,"min":8.84,"max":18.69,"night":11.51,"eve":13.43,"morn":8.84},"feels_like":{"day":16.14,"night":10.26,"eve":12.32,"morn":7.32},"pressure":1026,"humidity":39,"dew_point":2.71,"wind_speed":2.68,"wind_deg":124,"wind_gust":6.18,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":0,"pop":0,"uvi":3},{"dt":1644408000,"sunrise":1644392115,"sunset":1644429824,"moonrise":1644407940,"moonset":1644371940,"moon_phase":0.28,"temp":{"day":17.75,"min":10.34,"max":18.5,"night":14.17,"eve":15.25,"morn":10.34},"feels_like":{"day":16.7,"night":13.18,"eve":14.35,"morn":9.02},"pressure":1027,"humidity":43,"dew_point":4.69,"wind_speed":3.26,"wind_deg":133,"wind_gust":6.17,"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":88,"pop":0,"uvi":3},{"dt":1644494400,"sunrise":1644478447,"sunset":1644516296,"moonrise":1644496380,"moonset":1644461940,"moon_phase":0.31,"temp":{"day":16.66,"min":13.48,"max":16.84,"night":15.49,"eve":16.01,"morn":13.52},"feels_like":{"day":15.77,"night":14.82,"eve":15.31,"morn":12.49},"pressure":1026,"humidity":53,"dew_point":6.71,"wind_speed":5.27,"wind_deg":115,"wind_gust":10.08,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":100,"pop":0.36,"rain":0.43,"uvi":3}]}'
```

I tryed this, but doesn't work

```
const url2 = JSON.parse(url)
    let result = url2.current.map(({ dt, temp, weather: [{ description, icon }] }) => ({ dt, day }));
```

These two values I get doing this:

```
let day = url2.current.dt
let temp = url2.current.temp
console.log(day, temp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want to achieve, result is an array of dt, temp, description and icon from current and daily objects

```js
const str = '{"lat":39.7436,"lon":-8.8071,"timezone":"Europe/Lisbon","timezone_offset":0,"current":{"dt":1643884851,"sunrise":1643874091,"sunset":1643910991,"temp":8.11,"feels_like":6.94,"pressure":1025,"humidity":87,"dew_point":6.08,"uvi":1.63,"clouds":20,"visibility":7000,"wind_speed":2.06,"wind_deg":160,"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}]},"daily":[{"dt":1643889600,"sunrise":1643874091,"sunset":1643910991,"moonrise":1643880300,"moonset":1643920800,"moon_phase":0.08,"temp":{"day":9.56,"min":8.11,"max":14.8,"night":10.29,"eve":11.42,"morn":8.61},"feels_like":{"day":9.15,"night":9.8,"eve":10.78,"morn":8.61},"pressure":1025,"humidity":81,"dew_point":6.47,"wind_speed":2.51,"wind_deg":279,"wind_gust":2.99,"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"clouds":36,"pop":0,"uvi":2.12},{"dt":1643976000,"sunrise":1643960432,"sunset":1643997463,"moonrise":1643968320,"moonset":1644011220,"moon_phase":0.12,"temp":{"day":14.02,"min":9.3,"max":14.86,"night":9.66,"eve":11.67,"morn":9.3},"feels_like":{"day":13.17,"night":8.63,"eve":10.96,"morn":9.3},"pressure":1026,"humidity":65,"dew_point":7.18,"wind_speed":3.71,"wind_deg":335,"wind_gust":5.97,"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":100,"pop":0,"uvi":1.99},{"dt":1644062400,"sunrise":1644046772,"sunset":1644083936,"moonrise":1644056160,"moonset":1644101520,"moon_phase":0.15,"temp":{"day":14.98,"min":8.24,"max":16.46,"night":9.23,"eve":10.87,"morn":8.6},"feels_like":{"day":14.1,"night":8.89,"eve":10.23,"morn":8.6},"pressure":1026,"humidity":60,"dew_point":6.78,"wind_speed":2.88,"wind_deg":336,"wind_gust":4.08,"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":83,"pop":0,"uvi":2.57},{"dt":1644148800,"sunrise":1644133110,"sunset":1644170408,"moonrise":1644143940,"moonset":1644191700,"moon_phase":0.18,"temp":{"day":17.47,"min":8.59,"max":19.18,"night":11.06,"eve":13.31,"morn":8.59},"feels_like":{"day":16.4,"night":9.81,"eve":12.34,"morn":7.67},"pressure":1028,"humidity":43,"dew_point":4.4,"wind_speed":2.22,"wind_deg":18,"wind_gust":3.79,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":1,"pop":0,"uvi":2.62},{"dt":1644235200,"sunrise":1644219446,"sunset":1644256880,"moonrise":1644231840,"moonset":0,"moon_phase":0.22,"temp":{"day":18.22,"min":8.77,"max":19.22,"night":10.85,"eve":12.93,"morn":8.77},"feels_like":{"day":16.93,"night":9.3,"eve":11.56,"morn":7.52},"pressure":1028,"humidity":32,"dew_point":0.71,"wind_speed":3.49,"wind_deg":107,"wind_gust":5.75,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":3,"pop":0,"uvi":2.59},{"dt":1644321600,"sunrise":1644305782,"sunset":1644343352,"moonrise":1644319800,"moonset":1644281820,"moon_phase":0.25,"temp":{"day":17.33,"min":8.84,"max":18.69,"night":11.51,"eve":13.43,"morn":8.84},"feels_like":{"day":16.14,"night":10.26,"eve":12.32,"morn":7.32},"pressure":1026,"humidity":39,"dew_point":2.71,"wind_speed":2.68,"wind_deg":124,"wind_gust":6.18,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":0,"pop":0,"uvi":3},{"dt":1644408000,"sunrise":1644392115,"sunset":1644429824,"moonrise":1644407940,"moonset":1644371940,"moon_phase":0.28,"temp":{"day":17.75,"min":10.34,"max":18.5,"night":14.17,"eve":15.25,"morn":10.34},"feels_like":{"day":16.7,"night":13.18,"eve":14.35,"morn":9.02},"pressure":1027,"humidity":43,"dew_point":4.69,"wind_speed":3.26,"wind_deg":133,"wind_gust":6.17,"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":88,"pop":0,"uvi":3},{"dt":1644494400,"sunrise":1644478447,"sunset":1644516296,"moonrise":1644496380,"moonset":1644461940,"moon_phase":0.31,"temp":{"day":16.66,"min":13.48,"max":16.84,"night":15.49,"eve":16.01,"morn":13.52},"feels_like":{"day":15.77,"night":14.82,"eve":15.31,"morn":12.49},"pressure":1026,"humidity":53,"dew_point":6.71,"wind_speed":5.27,"wind_deg":115,"wind_gust":10.08,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":100,"pop":0.36,"rain":0.43,"uvi":3}]}';
const obj = JSON.parse(str)
const getData = ({ dt, temp, weather: [{ description, icon }] }) => {
           return {dt, temp, description, icon};
    }
const {current, daily} = obj;
const result = [getData(current)]
daily.forEach(obj=>result.push(getData(obj)));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: That was what I want but instead of temp: {day: 14.02, min: 9.3, max: 14.86, night: 9.66, eve: 11.67, morn: 9.3}, I need just day key with value.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you define a variable **result** where you try to map the contents to something but map is only used to loop through arrays and the url2.current is not an array.

The way to get your values is by using the keys for all your values except the weather which is in fact an array.

So for most keys you can extract them like this:

```
const url2 = JSON.parse(url);
const day = url2.current.dt;
```

I don't know what the expected output for weather is but if you try to output everything in a string that contains html you could do something like the following:

```
const weather = url2.current.weather.map((w) => `<span>${w.icon}</span>\n<p>${w.description}</p>`).join("\n");
```

You can replace the HTML tags with what works for you and just output weather.